# Coefficient of $x^3$ in expansion of $\frac{1}{e^x\cdot (1+x)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

> If $|x|<1$, then what is the coefficient of $x^3$ in expansion of $\dfrac{1}{e^x\cdot (1+x)}$?

**My Try:** So I rewrote this by taking $e^x$ to the numerator to get $\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+x)}$. My problem is, how can I deduce the coefficient of $x^3$ here, since I would need to divide the numerator by the denominator, which is a cumbersome task. Is there a simpler way? How can I solve problems like these? I'd love to know.

Comment: You just need that term. Do a few steps of the long division.

Comment: Is really long division the only method? What if I was asked the coefficient of $x^200$? I would certainly not divide then. There has to be another, more logical way.

Comment: Not all the terms of all Taylor series have nice expressions. Some of them may take a lot of effort. I, too, hate it when I need to calculate the $x^5$ term of $\tan x$. Here you can also rewrite $1/(1+x)=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$ and multiply that term-by-term with the series of $e^{-x}$. This is still easy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But in this case, both Taylor series are as nice as it gets...

Comment: @ClementC. Quite. But I still wouldn't want to calculate the $x^{200}$ term :-)

Comment: Fair point. If you *wanted* to do it, though, I'd be worried. :) @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{1}{e^x\cdot(1+x)}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-(-x)}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-x)^n}\right)\\
=\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)\cdot \left(1-x+x^2-x^3+o(x^3)\right).$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. Along the same lines, it can be seen that, more generally,  the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $\frac{1}{e^x\cdot(1+x)}$ is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\cdot (-1)^{n-k}=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}.$$
See the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) wiki page.

Comment: Okay, I see, but how does that help me? You know if there were two terms in the numerator and one in denominator I could easily solve. But not in this case.

Comment: @Tanuj Now you have to expand the product.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x} &=&\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots \right) (1- x+x^2-x^3+\cdots ) \\ &=&
\cdots +x^3 \underbrace{\left( -1-1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}\right)}_{\color{blue}{-\frac{8}{3}}}+ \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Can you explain what exactly did you do?

Comment: Wow a eureka moment for me! You used that result of infinite Geometric Progression, right?

Comment: Just used the standard expansions for the functions ...

Answer (score 1):

From the two Taylor series at $0$, to order $x^3$:$$
e^{-x} = 1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3) \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x+x^2-x^3+o(x^3)\tag{2}
$$
we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x} &= \left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)\right)\left(1-x+x^2-x^3+o(x^3)\right)\\
&= 1-x+x^2-x^3+o(x^3) - x+x^2-x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}\\
&= 1-2x+\frac{5}{2}x^2{\color{red}{-\frac{8}{3}}}x^3 +o(x^3)
\end{align}$$
and you can just read off the coefficient.

*Note that when expanding the product, we could have focused on only the terms $x^3$ (it would have been marginally faster, but would have required keeping track); and didn't expand any term $x^k$ with $k>3$, since anyway they are "swallowed" by the $o(x^3)$.*